# php sql Negative Days Result

Tags: php, sql

Just wondering why $days gives me a -0.511111111111 Days. The value of $dc_time->fields[0] is 2012-12-07 12:16:00. Can someone please troubleshoot? Thanks.

```
$dc_date = $dc_time->fields[0];
$today = date('Y-m-d');

$dc_date = strtotime($dc_date);
$today = strtotime($today);
$delta = $today - $dc_date;
$days= ($delta/86400);
```

Comment: I dont really see anything wrong with it? It's telling you that **7th Dec 2012 12:16** is approximately half a day ahead of you, which is (I don't know your timezone) probably correct. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: yeah but i do not know why it gives a negative (-) sign before the decimal. $today time here is 7th Dec 2012 15:10.

Comment: i can use abs and round but i think there something wrong. in my database the $dc_time->fields[0] is disconnecttm (column)smalldatetime(data type)

Comment: Sorry! Forgot that you may be in a different timezone. Am I right in saying you are in a *UTC/GMT +4 hours* timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$today` variable does not obtain a time, so it is set to the default (midnight).

Either give a time to your `$today`:

```
$dc_date = $dc_time->fields[0];
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$dc_date = strtotime($dc_date);
$today = strtotime($today);
$delta = $today - $dc_date;
$days= ($delta/86400);
```

Or if you don't actually need that, just get the timestamp straight away:

```
$dc_date = $dc_time->fields[0];

$dc_date = strtotime($dc_date);
$today = time();
$delta = $today - $dc_date;
$days= ($delta/86400);
```

Your script thinks that the time is in the future because `$today` would be [todays date] at 00:00:00am. I hope this helps.

Comment: This $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); is what I need and it solved the issue with the negative value. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped my friend.